# How to get the location data in ionic Angular code

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, geolocation, capacitor, capacitor-plugin

I  am creating a small ionic angular  app which uses Location and media. I have installed capacitor packages. Have used npm install @capacitor/geolocation,npm install @capacitor/camera.
1.Imported geolocation in the lcoation page.
2. This is the function I have used :

```
import { Geolocation } from '@capacitor/geolocation'; -  importing.
 async getCurrentLocation() {
    try {
      const coordinates = await Geolocation.getCurrentPosition();
      const latitude = coordinates.coords.latitude;
      const longitude = coordinates.coords.longitude;
      console.log(`Latitude: ${latitude}, Longitude: ${longitude}`);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error getting location', error);
    }
  }
```

3. I am not able to see the coordinates when I console this.
4. This is the html I have used

```
 <ion-button (click)="getCurrentLocation()">Get Location</ion-button>
```

5. PLease let me know if I am missing any thing related to location.
6. I need to get the coordinated of the location from the response.

Comment: Have you added the required permission in AndroidManifest.xml or Info.plist?

Comment: Did you run the command after installing plugin? npx cap sync

Answer (score 0):

1. Add required permissions for Android and iOS.
2. Add following code where you want current location

import { Geolocation } from '@capacitor/geolocation';

```
  import { GeoLocation } from '@capacitor/geolocation';
  
  await Geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then(geoPosition => {
  console.log("Geolocation", geoPosition);

    const coordinates: Coordinates = {
      lat: geoPosition.coords.latitude,
      lng: geoPosition.coords.longitude
    };
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```